# How can I show the fields "Task Subject" & "Task Comments" as a column in an Opportunity List View

Tags: list-view

[image]

I want to be able to see Task Fields in this Opportunity List View below. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about doing this? Specifically, i want to display the Task Subject & Task Comments for the most recent open Task.

Should I just create formula fields at the opp level to pull through the task fields? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since the tasks are children of the opportunity (1:M relationship) you can have multiple tasks related to 1 opportunity.

There is no standard functionality that will allow you to pull up the most recent task so you'll probably need to create additional fields on the opportunity object and have an apex trigger on the Task object that will determine the most recent open task and populate the fields on the opportunity (Task Subject and Task Comments, as well as Task ID which you can use together with the other 2 fields to create a formula field - hyperlink to the actual task record).